# data not updated in json file with javascript using fetch

Tags: javascript, json, fetch-api

i want to update data in json file , insert data is working but when i want to update existing data,it is added to the file (i get new data in json file, not replace the existing one)

```
let resultat = '' ; const url = 'http://localhost:3000/etudiants' ;

etudiantList.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
e.preventDefault() ; 
let suppButtonClick = e.target.id == 'supprimer-etudient' ;
let modButtonClick = e.target.id == 'modifier-etudient' ; 

let id = e.target.parentElement.dataset.id;
//supprimer un etudiant 

if(suppButtonClick){
   fetch(`${url}/${id}`,{
       method:'DELETE',

   })
   .then(res => res.json() )
   .then(() => location.reload())
}

if(modButtonClick) {
    const parent = e.target.parentElement.parentElement ; 
    let nomCont = parent.querySelector('.nomPrenom').textContent ;
    let niveauCont = parent.querySelector('.niveau').textContent ;
    let naissanceCont = parent.querySelector('.dateNaissance').textContent ;
    let massarCont = parent.querySelector('.codeMassar').textContent ;
    let imageCont = parent.querySelector('.imageEtu').textContent ;

    NomValeur.value = nomCont ; 
    NiveauValeur.value = niveauCont ; 
    NaissanceValeur.value = naissanceCont ; 
    MassarValeur.value = massarCont ; 
    ImageValeur.value = imageCont ; 
}

// update data here 

btnSubmit.addEventListener('click' , (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
fetch(`${url}/${id}`,{
    method:'PATCH',
    headers:{
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json' 
    },

body:JSON.stringify({
        Nom:NomValeur.value,
        Niveau:NiveauValeur.value,
        DateNaissance:NaissanceValeur.value,
        CodeMassar:MassarValeur.value,
        Image:ImageValeur.value

    }) 
})

.then(res => res.json() )
.then(() => location.reload())

})
```

} ) ;

HTML CODE

```
            <div id="ajouter-invisible-espace" style="display: none;" class=" card mb-3">
          <div class="card-header">
            <span><i class="bi bi-table me-2"></i></span> Opérations sur la liste
          </div>
          <div class="card-body ">
            <form class="ajouter-etudiant" action="">
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="title">Nome et Prénom</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Nom-valeur">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Niveau">Niveau</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Niveau-valeur">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Naissance"> Date de Naissance</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Naissance-valeur">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Massar">    Code MASSAR</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Massar-valeur">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="title">Image</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Image-valeur">
              </div>

             <div class="form-group my-3">
              <button type="submit" class="btnModifier btn btn-primary">Ajouter</button>
             </div>
             

            </form>

          </div>
        </div>
```

i am using the same button for add data and update data, and 1 more thing preventDefault is not working in update

add function

```
ajouterEtudiant.addEventListener('submit', (e) =>{
e.preventDefault() ;

fetch(url,{
    method:'POST',
    headers:{
       'Content-Type' : 'application/json' 
    },

 body:JSON.stringify({
        Nom:NomValeur.value,
        Niveau:NiveauValeur.value,
        DateNaissance:NaissanceValeur.value,
        CodeMassar:MassarValeur.value,
        Image:ImageValeur.value

    }) 

})
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data => {
    const dataArr =[] ; 
    dataArr.push(data) ; 
    afficherEtudiants(data);
})
```

})

Comment: So you make a PATCH request … and what server-side code is supposed to handle it?

Comment: Yeah, not 100% certain but it looks like a server-side code issue.  Do you use the same PATCH request to "add" and "modify" a record?  Does the server code know how to tell them apart?

Comment: i have server i will add the full code

Comment: yes and it's working good